# Using Bootstrap 4 with Grails

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grails, bootstrap-4

I'm using Grails for a web project for a CSE class in college. I've noticed many of the other groups doing this project are using Bootstrap 4 for the web design (I'm in the only group using Grails). I looked into Bootstrap 4 and I really love the way it looks. Personally I don't like the way Grails looks with standard HTML. I was wondering if there is a way that I can use Bootstrap 4 with Grails. For example in standard HTML I can have a button and forms that will submit data to a controller and some action will happen, it doesn't seem to work the same way with Grails.

Would anyone know if I can integrate Bootstrap 4 with Grails and if so how I can do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bootstrap has nothing to do with Grails. Just include the dependencies and use the bootstrap classes in your GSP just like you'd do in a plain HTML page. You can use the `<g:form>` tag to post to your Grails controller.

Comment: "You can use the tag to post to your Grails controller." - To which tag are you referring?

Comment: `<g:form>` - somehow that got stripped from my answer. Answer updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In your newly created app you will see that under `grails-app/assets/stylesheets/` are a number of `.css` files including `bootstrap.css` and under `grails-app/assets/javascripts/` you will find `bootstrap.js`.  We put those there by default and many people use them, but you don't have to.  Drop whatever assets you like in those folders and then you can use them.  You may want to edit `grails-app/assets/javascripts/application.js` and `grails-app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` to pull in whatever assets you add to the project and you would do that with the `require` directive.  See the contents of those files for examples.

I hope that helps.

Comment: To jeff's answer I would only add that to install client dependencies you should use https://github.com/craigburke/client-dependencies-gradle

Answer (score 1):

### Steps:

- Download `bootstrap-4.X.X.zip`
- Extract the .zip archive and open the `dist` directory
- In your Grails 3 app, replace `grails-app/assets/stylesheets/boostrap.css` with `dist/css/bootstrap.css`
- Delete `grails-app/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js`
- Copy `dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js` into the `grails-app/assets/javascripts` directory
- Make the following change in `grails-app/assets/javascripts`

**Replace:**

`//= require bootstrap`

**With:**

`//= require bootstrap.bundle`

### Optional:

Upgrade the jQuery dependency. Version 2.2.0 of jQuery that ships with Grails by default is quite old. Bootstrap 4 should work with all 3.X versions of jQuery.

Comment: Tried these steps.  Used Bootstrap 4.1.0 and jQuery 3.1.1.  The navigation menu does not render for a big screen.  It only renders as for a mobile device.  Used the latest (23 April 2018) Grails 3.3.5.  Clearly, the html created by Grails is still as for Bootstrap 3.

Comment: In addition to my comment yesterday; after replacing all the navabar html markup in main.gsp and index.gsp with valid Bootstrap4 navbar markup - very different from the Bootstrap3 navbar markup still found in Grails - it worked.  It also works for domain classes and controllers generated.  One will have to do some css styling for the navbar, but that's a minor.